# Can I declare dbcontext without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm building a tools which convert Entity Framework model object to another object. The new object should save as a file. I declare an object like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CreateBusinessObjectByEF
{
    class BusinessObjectBuilder
    {
        private DbContext db;
        private DbSet dbSet;
    }
}
```

But the string `DbContext` and `DbSet` is marked by red line because namespace error. I have add the reference to `System.Data.Entity`, and I don't want to add the reference to Entity Framework, because I want my application can run on all the version of EF.

So who can help me? Thanks

Comment: You're going to use types from `EntityFramework.dll` (`DbContext` and `DbSet`) and don't want to add a reference to `EntityFramework.dll`. Am I missing something? If I'm not, then this is impossible. If you want to be EF version-agnostic, throw away `DbContext` API and use `ObjectContext` one. Note, that this approach won't work with EF 7 (which will throw away `ObjectContext` API at all, AFAIK). Maybe, you will tell us about your real task?

Comment: That just won't work.

Comment: @Dennis No you are not missing anything. OP is expecting too much from .NET framework. :)

Comment: @Dennis,  I just want to be EF version-agnostic, because what I need is fetch the DbSets in DbContext and build a new class file by the properties of DbSet. So I think this application can be EF version-agnostic. Am I right?

Comment: @user2155362: what is your input? Is it C# source code or compiled assembly? Do you need `DbContext` and `DbSet` properties in `BusinessObjectBuilder`? If so, what for? Maybe, reflection will help you?

Comment: OK, I think I got it, I needn't DbContext, I needn't DbSet, what I need is one object which contain special type of objects

Comment: @Dennis, yes, reflection! The input is compiled assembly, and the output is C# source code. I read the DbContext as a normal object and find dbsets in this object. I can special the dbset by string, and get them by reflection. It's right?